# Internet Explorer reports "content with security certificate errors" but only on one machine

Tags: security, internet-explorer, ssl

Good morning all!

I am a sysadmin with a medium-sized business. I'm in workstation support, not part of the web team or server support. I have a single user who gets an information bar at the bottom of IE every time he opens our own company's homepage:

> Internet Explorer blocked this website from displaying content with security certificate errors.

I am pretty sure this is a workstation issue, and not serverside. I cannot replicate the problem on any of our other machines. The browser still navigates out to the site, it doesn't show the "There is a problem with this website's security certificate" page and try to block access.

I have opened the certificate by clicking on the padlock icon in IE and I can't see any warnings about the certificate. Did the same in Chrome and can't find any issues.

I did a Clear SSL State in IE on the user's machine, and the issue still isn't resolved. Other HTTPS sites work appropriately.

As this is our own URL, it is a trusted site in IE by group policy. I have checked that the same is true on the user's machine.

At this point I am not 100% sure that there isn't actually an issue I need to report to the web team. Nothing I have tried seems to be able to clear this single machine of the notion that something is wrong with that certificate but I can't confirm it either way.

The website's URL is https://www.ruffalonl.com/

Assuming nothing is wrong with the site or the certificate, does anyone know a way of suppressing the blasted message in IE? Either I make this message go away, or I am going to get a support ticket from this user that says something is wrong with the website every single day until I die.

Comment: I would look into the user's machine certificates under Trusted Root Certification Authorities and confirm that there is only one certificate for your company website. It is possible that the certificate in the store is corrupted, or outdated. You could try removing it and reinstalling the certificate.

Comment: It is probably a resource on the page from another domain that doesn't have a certificate that is trusted by that workstation.